# Report: Counting number of records, between a number range

Tags: ms-access-2013

MS Access 2013.  I need to write a report that shows the number of books inside our storage boxes.

All books purchased are given a unique nbr (SaleID).  We store 25 books per box, and 100 books takes 4 boxes.  As we sell books, they are removed from their specific boxes, and over time, lets say 30 books are sold.  We can then discard one box, and store the remaining 70 books in three boxes.  We have thousands of books and hundreds of storage boxes.  I need to run a report that shows me how many books are in stock, per every 100 books, so that I can reduce the number of boxes (and save storage space).

The report should show like this:

001 - 100  34  (i.e. 34 books are in stock in the number range 001 to 100.

101 - 200  35  (35 books in stock)

201 - 300  22  (22 books in stock)

301 - 400  60  (60 books in stock)
etc

The query below does what I want, where I enter the criteria of the hundred books being queried.  But I need a line on the report, for each hundred books, for all the books we hold.

```
SELECT tblSale.BookInStock, Count(tblSale.BookInStock) AS [Total Books]
FROM tblSale
WHERE (((tblSale.SaleID) Between 4201 And 4300))
GROUP BY tblSale.BookInStock
HAVING (((tblSale.BookInStock)=Yes));
```

If someone has any ideas I'd be grateful for your thoughts
Cheers
Nev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have to query every hundred items, coding will be needed to run through every per hundred batch. Therefore, consider creating a temp table from a VBA looped query.

First iteration of loop  creates the table replacing previous, then all other iterations append by hundred batches (notice step used to skip iterator forward) across your thousands. By the way, your `HAVING` clause condition was moved to `WHERE` clause.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim sqlStr As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tbl As TableDef

Set db = CurrentDb

For Each tbl in db.TableDefs
  If tbl.Name = "BoxBooksPerHundred" Then
     db.TableDefs.Delete(tbl.Name)
  End If
Next tbl

For i = 1 to 4300 Step 100  ' ADJUST AS NEEDED
   If i = 1 Then
        ' MAKE-TABLE QUERY
        strsql= "SELECT '" & i & " - " & i + 100 & "' AS [HundredRange], tblSale.BookInStock," _
              & " Count(tblSale.BookInStock) AS [Total Books]" _
              & " INTO BoxBooksPerHundred FROM tblSale" _ 
              & " WHERE (((tblSale.BookInStock)=Yes)) And" _ 
              & "       (((tblSale.SaleID) Between " & i & " And " & i + 100 & "))" _ 
              & " GROUP BY '" & i & " - " & i + 100 & "', tblSale.BookInStock;"
        db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
   Else 
        ' APPEND QUERY
        strsql= "INSERT INTO BoxBooksPerHundred (HundredRange, BookInStock, [Total Books])"
              & " SELECT '" & i & " - " & i + 100 & "' AS [HundredRange], tblSale.BookInStock," _
              & " Count(tblSale.BookInStock) AS [Total Books]" _
              & " FROM tblSale" _ 
              & " WHERE (((tblSale.BookInStock)=Yes)) And" _ 
              & "       (((tblSale.SaleID) Between " & i & " And " & i + 100 & "))" _ 
              & " GROUP BY '" & i & " - " & i + 100 & "', tblSale.BookInStock;"
        db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
   End If
Next i

Set tbl = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Run this loop on the trigger event that opens report. But since quite a bit of data, try triggering on database open if you expect data not to change often. Ultimately, use this temp table, BooksPerHundred, as recordsource for report.

Comment: Thanks close but not quite.  I've added Dim strSQL As String.

Comment: I've added Dim strSQL As String.  I've added the code to the on-click event of a command button.

When it runs, it gives me a runtime error 3000, Reserved error (-3002) There is no message for this error.

In the debugger this line is highlighted
db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

In access the table has been created. And the first record is there i.e. 
1-101 -1  24 

where 24 is the number of books in that block of 100.

If I click and run it again, it tells me the table "BoxBooksPerHundred exists. and the debugger highlights line

db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError in the make table query.

Comment: See edit. Temp table is now deleted if it exists prior to being recreated.

Comment: Still have the same problem.  The table is created, and the result from the first block of 100 is written to table BoxBooksPerHundred.  Then I get the msgbox with "Run-time error 3000: Reserved error (-3002); there is no message for this error."

The debugger has stopped under Else on db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

I appreciate your help with this.  cheers

Comment: Try it again, Nev. Previous append query had a Make-Table query's `INTO` clause which I removed.

Comment: Works perfectly!!  I'm very pleased with your answer Parfait!  Exactly what I was looking for.  Cheers mate!!!